# WDDX and Russian Characters

Tags: xml, coldfusion, wddx

I'm looking to convert data into an XML output via WDDX

However the output crashes on russian characters - I'm informed that this is to happen - however I'm open to solutions for ways around this if anyone is aware?

Code is as below:

```
<cfwddx action="cfml2wddx" input="#variables.csPages#" output="variables.xmlOutput" />
<cfset variables.xmlOutput = ReplaceNoCase(variables.xmlOutput, "&lt;", "<", "all")>
<cfset variables.xmlOutput = ReplaceNoCase(variables.xmlOutput, "&gt;", ">", "all")>
<cfset variables.xmlOutput = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' & variables.xmlOutput>
<cffile action="write" file="#variables.filePath#" output="#variables.xmlOutput#" charset="utf-8" />
```

Error is as follows:
A string literal was expected, but no opening quote character was found. Error processing resource 'file:///D:/csroot/dev/c...

```
<var name='includePageTitle'><string>1</string></var><var name='IncludeRightColumn'><string...PAN>> </DIV> <char code="0a" />
```

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: Can you pls give us a sample of the input for `variables.csPages`? Doesn't have to be complete, just enough to force the problem so we can emulate what you're doing locally.  Can you please also post the actual error (line numbers, code extract, top of the stack trace, etc)

Comment: Two things I would try 1) Can you do a simple CFOUTPUT of the data? 2) Does it crash on the first character it sees or only certain characters?

Answer (score 0):

Use the element in question as a standalone file, such as `russian.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
 <root>
  <var name='includePageTitle'><string>1</string></var><var name='IncludeRightColumn'><string...PAN>> </DIV> <char code="0a" />
 </root>
```

Use `xmllint` to find the errors:

```
xmllint russian.xml
```

> russian.xml:3: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: string...PAN line 3 and DIV
>   e'>1> 
>                                                                                  ^
>   russian.xml:4: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: var line 3 and root
>   
>          ^
>   russian.xml:5: parser error : Premature end of data in tag root line 2

**References**

- [Character Model for the World Wide Web: Unique Character Encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/charmod/#C018)
- [XMLSoft: xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)